# Failing to load all sounds through JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a kind of game in javascript using css3 and html5. The game uses multiple sounds (currently 156). Most of them are very short - up to 3sec. I load them at the start, store them in array and according to user actions play them. Here's the code for it:

```
var Sounds=[];
var SoundsLoaded = 0;

function AddSound( filename )
{
    var sound = new Audio();          //creating  a new sound for the game
    sound.src = filename;
    sound.loop = false;
    sound.autoplay=false;
    sound.autobuffer=true;
    sound.preload="auto";

    Sounds.push( sound );            //add it to the container
}

function LoadSounds()
{
    for( i = 0; < src.length; i++)   //altogether about 150 files
       AddSound( src[i] );

    for( i = 0; i < Sounds.length; i++ )
    {
        Sounds[i].addEventListener( "loadeddata", function()
        { 
            SoundsLoaded++;

            if( SoundsLoaded == Sounds.length )
            {
                 AllSoundsLoaded();     //continue when all sounds are ready to use
            }
        });

        Sounds[i].addEventListener( "error", function()
        {
             alert(this.error.code);          //alerts with code 4
             alert(this.networkState);        //alerts with state 3
        });

        Sounds[i].load();
    } 
 }
```

Everything is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but there's a problem for opera and IE:
After few sounds are loaded, errors occure: 
MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED (4) and NETWORK_NO_SOURCE (3)

It's very strange for me why there are errors, because:

1. i'm sure that audio files are there
2. chrome and firefox load all files correctly
3. all audio files are in the same directory
4. all audio files uses the same codec (audio/x-vorbis+ogg) or (audio/mpeg). src i use is set before- mp3 for IE ogg for all others
5. it happened few times that opera loaded less then 32 files but in 9/10 cases opera loads !!!exactly!!! 32 of 156 sounds, and these files are not all the same
   6.any suggestions to solve it? i would like to avoid to merge more sounds into the one and play only appropriate parts

tested browsers: opera 11.62, ff 11, chromium 18, ie (9),

Has anybody met this behaviour? 
Did i forget or should i set some Audio element property?
Does opera (and IE) have cache restriction for number of loaded sounds? is it possible to change it using JS?